# open compose mail of outlook on click of a button in asp.net mvc3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a button in my view.On click of that it has to open compose mail with "TO" field populated with email id of logged in user,also some predefined data has to be in that mail .

please help me for solving this.thanks in advance.

Comment: this is huge, How you are saving logged in user, and how you have designed your view and what data you need to show by default.

Comment: I am saving the logged in user in cookies.
in my view there is a table ,that entire table data i need to show in mail,
my button is like this
<span id="SubmitWeeklySalesReportForVP" class="FormButtonBlue">Submit</span>
on click of this button i need to open compose mail.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <a href="mailto:abc@abc.com?Subject=XYZ&Body=Hello" title="XYZ" >
```